# SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string error typeORM

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm, dotenv

```
Error: SASL: SCRAM-SERVER-FIRST-MESSAGE: client password must be a string
```

I looked for some solutions for this one in the stack overflow and many say it would be a dotenv problem, but in my case the application was working normally before without any modification in dotenv, I already tried to import in other ways and the error continues, so I believe that it's a typeORM error.

database config

```
import { DataSource } from "typeorm"
import { User } from "../entities/User"

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: "postgres",
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    port: 5432,
    username: process.env.DATABASE_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.DATABASE_NAME,
    synchronize: true,
    logging: true,
    entities: [User],
    subscribers: [],
    migrations: [],
})
```

entity User

```
import { BeforeInsert, BeforeUpdate, Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from "typeorm";
import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

@Entity('users')
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column()
    username: string;

    @Column()
    email: string;

    @Column()
    password: string;

    @BeforeInsert()
    @BeforeUpdate()
    hashPassword() {
        this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 8);
    }
}
```

app

```
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import 'reflect-metadata';

import userRoutes from './src/routes/UserRoutes';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use('/user', userRoutes)

export default app;
```

server

```
import app from './app';
import { AppDataSource } from './src/database/Config';

async function connection() {
    const port = process.env.PORT;
    try {
        await AppDataSource.initialize();
        console.log('Database connected! ');
        app.listen(port);
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

connection();
```

Answer (score 1):

After literal days of searching online for a solution (there are none... until now), I found my own through trial and error.

## Why this happens

Despite what some say about **dotenv** or your **.env** file being the problem, the root cause is not client side but server side, a local configuration oversight with postgres.

Postgres uses a peer authentication method for local connections by default, meanwhile Node's **pg** package uses scram-sha-256 (wrongfully assuming you are connecting to a remote server).

This causes the error since Node tries sending the server a scram authentication request, despite the server having already authenticated the app via the peer method.

This is also why you can connect to the database, but are still getting the error.

Node sends a scram request, the request is consumed but not used by the server, Node sees the response and assumes that the consumed password was blank, raising the error above.

## What is the solution?

Firstly, ensure you have a postgres account password set. This same error can be caused if your postgres account password is blank. You can skip this if you did it when you first configured postgres.

Do this by switching to your postgres account, accessing the database "postgres" then changing the password to something not null

```
sudo su postgres 
psql postgres 
\password
```

After a password has been set, you need to change the server authentication methods for postgres.

Do this by editing the pg_hba.conf file

> /etc/postgresql/15/main/pg_hba.conf

so that all local/host connections used the scram-sha-256 authentication method.

By default, the lines

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

and

```
local   all             all                                     peer
```

will have the authentication method [peer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-peer.html).

The same method is set default for the other local and host policies. This peer method is what causes you the error.

**Fix this by changing the method from peer to scram-sha-256**

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                scram-sha-256

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     scram-sha-256

# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256

# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256

# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256`
```

If anything else is peer, change it to scram-sha-256.

After this is done, exit from the postgres account and restart the postgresql process to reload the config

```
exit
sudo systemctl restart postgresql
```

Now, inside your Node App, use a connection object or your environment variables to connect.

For .env, ensure your variables names are set in accordance with the default Postgres names listed [here](https://node-postgres.com/apis/client).

For example, the default password environment variable should be **PGPASSWORD**. So in your .env file, you should have the password as

```
PGPASSWORD = "MyPassword"
```

For the connection object method, create an object and feed it into your **new Client(ObjectHere)**

```
const ConObj = {
    user: "postgres", // default process.env.PGUSER || process.env.USER
    password: "password", //default process.env.PGPASSWORD
    host: "localhost", // default process.env.PGHOST
    database: "my_test_database", // default process.env.PGDATABASE || user
    port: 5432, // default process.env.PGPORT
    application_name: "My Application Name", // The name of the application that created this Client instance
}

const dbConnection = new Client(ConObj)
dbConnection.connect()
```

Once all of this is done, the error should be resolved.

Hopefully this helps someone out there, I was pulling my hair out with this error. Glad its gone...